# Bad Request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, openweathermap

When I  run the program below to get a request from openweathermap for the weather, I am getting a 400 status code. Does anyone know how I can get a working status code along with the weather.

```
import requests

city = input("What is the name of the city?: ")
output = (requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + "&appid=*************"))
print(output)
```

Comment: You never add the value of `city` to the URL. You probably also need to urlencode the city name in case there are spaces or other non-alphabetic characters in it.

Comment: `...q=" + city + "&app...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help

```
import requests

city = input("What is the name of the city?: ")
url= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid=*************".format(city=city)
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

Comment: Is there anyway for me to get more information than just the status code?

Comment: ya you can just add this code ```data = response.json()
print(data)```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you were not including the city in the url, which is why it is returning an error response.

Secondly, this may not work for cities with spaces, for example, New York.

Try encoding the url like this

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse

city = input("What is the name of the city?: ")
param = {'q': city, 'appid': 'YourAppID'}

url = urllib.parse.urljoin \
    ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
     urllib.parse.urlencode(param)
     )

output = (requests.get(url))
print(output)
```